# Write from one parent to multiple children?

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I am learning Pipes and Forks. In this instance I am trying to write the same word from the parent to its children. Here is some practise code I wrote (four children):

```
#define MAXWORD 5

int main() {

    pid_t parentID, pid, fd[2];
    int i, j, k;
    int status = 0;
    char toWrite[5] = "abcd";

    pipe(fd);
    parentID = getpid();

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        if (getpid() == parentID) {
            pid = fork();
        }

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);

        } else if (pid == 0) {
            close(fd[1]);

            printf("Reading ...\n");            
            char buf[MAXWORD];
            read(fd[0], buf, MAXWORD);

            printf("CHILD : %d\tread : %s\n", getpid(), buf);

            exit(0); // edited

        }

    }

    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        if (getpid() == parentID) {
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("Writing ...\n");
            write(fd[1], toWrite, MAXWORD);

            wait(&status); // edited
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from the code:

```
Reading ...
Writing ...
CHILD : 1457    read : abcd
Writing ...
Reading ...
Reading ...
Writing ...
Writing ...
CHILD : 1458    read : abcd
CHILD : 1457    read : abcd
Reading ...
Reading ...
CHILD : 1458    read : abcd
Reading ...
Reading ...
Reading ...
CHILD : 1458    read : abcd
CHILD : 1459    read : 
Reading ...
CHILD : 1459    read : 
CHILD : 1460    read : 
CHILD : 1457    read : abcd
Reading ...
CHILD : 1457    read : abcd
```

If I put the write statements in an else if clause in the loop where the forking is done it works fine. However, in the case where I try to write after the children have been created it don't work well.

**EDIT:** After added the lines marked "edited", the program works as expected. Would this be the correct way of doing it?

And inputs are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the parent exits, the pipe closes.  The children will then have their reads satisfied with 0 bytes.  (You should check the return code from the read.)  Each child is also reading N times due to the loop.  The first child 4 times, the second child 3 times, etc.  Since all of the children are reading the same pipe, any one of them could satisfy the read.

Comment: The last point you made has been bothering me. Should I not have the write in a loop?

Comment: A usual method is to fork the children in a loop.  Then after the loop, do the read with an if (getpid() != parentID) around it.  This will result in each child doing 1 read.  This would mean that each child will get one write.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! That works very well. However, if the write also done similarly?

Comment: Your writes are OK because of the if check in the loop.  Only the parent will do writes.  Better would be to put the if around the loop.  This makes it easier to read.